# SharpGL - Entering Active Rendering Loop

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering

I've successfully setup my frame with the `OpenGLControl` and delegated my `render` method to the `OpenGLDraw` event of it. However, I'd like to do game programming so I want to enter into an active rendering loop where I'd update the game state and render, both from another thread but can't figure it to do how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by not calling `Application.Run` and instead using `P/Invoke` to create a `C++` styled `MessagePump`.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but if it works the same as most other systems you will need to make sure that all the OpenGL calls come from the thread, past that you can put your logic and everything else is however mean and whichever threads you want. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Winforms `Application.Idle` event?

Example (assuming you have a standard static class Program):

In Main - `Application.Idle += Tick`

```
static void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Insert rendering/updating code here
}
```